# 3d grid cell calculation

Tags: 3d

i am not sure if i selected correct category for my question.
Lets say i have a 2d grid. Every cell in the grid has an id which is calculated using formula:
`currentRow * totalColumns + currentColumn + 1`. So if you have a grid with 5 rows and 4 columns and cell with x,y coordinates: 3, 0 its id is 13.

Now in reverse if i want to find x,y coordinates based only on cell Id and total row and columns i will do this:

```
row = (id - 1) / totalColumns
column = (id - 1) % totalColumns
```

What i want is to add a third dimension (which will make the grid a cube), lets name it slices. So i now calculate the cellid using the formula:

```
currentRow * totalColumns + currentColumn + currentSlice + 1
```

But i cant find out how to do the reverse operation, how to find the x,y,z coordinates based on cellid and total rows columns and slices.

Comment: Your cellid formula isn't 1-1.  (row,column,slice)=(1,2,3) maps to the same value as (1,3,2).

Comment: you are right, but then how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your new formula is that it is maping different cells to the same id. You need something a bit more complex than that.

You can try

```
currentSlice * totalRows * totalColumns + currentRow * totalColumns + currentColumn + 1
```

You can show this function now maps every cell to a unique id.

To get your coordinates back you do something similar:

```
column = (id - 1) % totalColumns
row = ((id - column - 1)/totalColumns) % totalRows
slice = (((id - column - 1)/totalColumns)-row) / totalRows
```

This can be generalized to a $n $-dimensional table.

Comment: yes this looks correct!, thanks!